# Two GPUs Good, Three Bad

Tags: boot, ethernet

I've encountered an odd problem that I can't seem to run down. I've built an Ubuntu 16.04.3 server for mining with multiple AMD RX580s. It works fine with one or two GPUs, but when I add the third, something goes haywire. The network interface never starts up. I can log in via the terminal, but I can't get any of the network services to start.

This is my second rig - I've got the first one up and running with six GPUs and no issues. I'm using the same motherboard (ASUS z270-p prime). The GPUs are similar, but not quite the same. I'm having the problem with Asus Radeon 580s (I used XFX RX 580s in the working rig).

I've been looking through kernel log to see if I can figure out where things are going sideways, but I'm not having any luck yet. I'm struggling with where to look next - any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Additional information:

- Bios and OS have been updated
- Cards work in other systems

I looked in the boot.log and found the following:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
See 'systemctl status networking.service' for details.
```

When I run *systemctl status networking.service* I get the following:

> networking.service - Raise network interfaces    Loaded: loaded
>   (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset:
>   enabled)   Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
>              └─50-insserv.conf-$network.conf
>           /etc/systemd/system/networking.service.d
>              └─override.conf    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-12-10 18:31:22 EST; 1min 23s ago
>        Docs: man:interfaces(5)   Process: 961 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)   Process: 883 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n
>   "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm
>   settle (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 961 (code=exited,
>   status=1/FAILURE)
>
> Dec 10 18:31:22 BigServer2 ifup[961]: than a configuration issue
>   please read the section on submitting Dec 10 18:31:22 BigServer2
>   ifup[961]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README
>   file Dec 10 18:31:22 BigServer2 ifup[961]: before submitting a bug. 
>   These pages explain the proper Dec 10 18:31:22 BigServer2 ifup[961]:
>   process and the information we find helpful for debugging.. Dec 10
>   18:31:22 BigServer2 ifup[961]: exiting. Dec 10 18:31:22 BigServer2
>   ifup[961]: Failed to bring up enp5s0. Dec 10 18:31:22 BigServer2
>   systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited,
>   status=1/FAILURE Dec 10 18:31:22 BigServer2 systemd[1]: Failed to
>   start Raise network interfaces. Dec 10 18:31:22 BigServer2 systemd[1]:
>   networking.service: Unit entered failed state. Dec 10 18:31:22
>   BigServer2 systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result
>   'exit-code'.

Comment: Is the PSU enough?

Comment: Thanks for asking. Yes, it's a 1000W PSU, same as on the working rig. I'm thinking it's more likely a hardware conflict, probably related to PCI, but I don't know enough about reading log files to figure it out.

Comment: Some additional information: bios has been updated, updates applied to Ubuntu.